# Simple Thrust code performs about half as fast as my naive cuda kernel. Am I using Thrust wrong?

Tags: c++, cuda, gpgpu, thrust

I'm pretty new to Cuda and Thrust, but my impression was that Thrust, when used well, is supposed to offer better performance than naively written Cuda kernels. Am I using Thrust in a sub-optimal way? Below is a complete, minimal example that takes an array `u` of length `N+2`, and for each `i` between `1` and `N` computes the average `0.5*(u[i-1] + u[i+1])` and puts the result in `uNew[i]`. (`uNew[0]` is set to `u[0]` and `u[N+1]` is set to `u[N+1]` so that the boundary terms don't change). The code performs this averaging a large number of times to get reasonable times for timing tests. On my hardware, the Thrust computation takes roughly twice as long as the naive code. Is there a way to improve my Thrust code?

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <boost/timer.hpp>
#include <thrust/device_malloc.h>

typedef double numtype;

template <typename T> class NeighborAverageFunctor{
 int N;
public:
 NeighborAverageFunctor(int _N){
  N = _N;
 }
 template <typename Tuple>
 __host__ __device__ void operator()(Tuple t){
  T uL = thrust::get<0>(t);
  T uR = thrust::get<1>(t);

  thrust::get<2>(t) = 0.5*(uL + uR);
 }

 int getN(){
  return N;
 }
};

template <typename T> void thrust_sweep(thrust::device_ptr<T> u, thrust::device_ptr<T> uNew, NeighborAverageFunctor<T>& op){
 int N = op.getN();
 thrust::for_each(thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(u, u + 2, uNew + 1)), thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(u + N, u + N+2, uNew + N+1)), op);
 // Propagate boundary values without changing them
 uNew[0] = u[0];
 uNew[N+1] = u[N+1];
}


template <typename T> __global__ void initialization_kernel(int n, T* u){
 const int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
 if(i < n+2){
  if(i == 0){
   u[i] = 1.0;
  }
  else{
   u[i] = 0.0;
  }
 }
}

template <typename T> __global__ void sweep_kernel(int n, T, T* u, T* uNew){
 const int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
 if (i >= 1 && i < n-1){
  uNew[i] = 0.5*(u[i+1] + u[i-1]);
 }
 else if(i == 0 || i == n+1){
  uNew[i] = u[i];
 }
}

int main(void){
 int sweeps = 2000;
 int N = 4096*2048;
 numtype h = 1.0/N;
 numtype hSquared = pow(h, 2);

 NeighborAverageFunctor<numtype> op(N);

 thrust::device_ptr<numtype> u_d = thrust::device_malloc<numtype>(N+2);
 thrust::device_ptr<numtype> uNew_d = thrust::device_malloc<numtype>(N+2);
 thrust::device_ptr<numtype> uTemp_d;

 thrust::fill(u_d, u_d + (N+2), 0.0);
 u_d[0] = 1.0;

 boost::timer::timer timer1;

 for(int k = 0; k < sweeps; k++){
  thrust_sweep<numtype>(u_d, uNew_d, op);
  uTemp_d = u_d;
  u_d = uNew_d;
  uNew_d = uTemp_d;
 }

 double thrust_time = timer1.elapsed();

 thrust::host_vector<numtype> u_h(N+2);
 thrust::copy(u_d, u_d + N+2, u_h.begin());
 for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  std::cout << u_h[i] << " ";
 }
 std::cout << std::endl;

 thrust::device_free(u_d);
 thrust::device_free(uNew_d);

 numtype * u_raw_d, * uNew_raw_d, * uTemp_raw_d;
 cudaMalloc(&u_raw_d, (N+2)*sizeof(numtype));
 cudaMalloc(&uNew_raw_d, (N+2)*sizeof(numtype));

 numtype * u_raw_h = (numtype*)malloc((N+2)*sizeof(numtype));

 int block_size = 256;
 int grid_size = ((N+2) + block_size - 1) / block_size;

 initialization_kernel<numtype><<<grid_size, block_size>>>(N, u_raw_d);

 boost::timer::timer timer2;

 for(int k = 0; k < sweeps; k++){
  sweep_kernel<numtype><<<grid_size, block_size>>>(N+2, hSquared, u_raw_d, uNew_raw_d);
  uTemp_raw_d = u_raw_d;
  u_raw_d = uNew_raw_d;
  uNew_raw_d = uTemp_raw_d;
 }

 double raw_time = timer2.elapsed();

 cudaMemcpy(u_raw_h, u_raw_d, (N+2)*sizeof(numtype), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

 for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  std::cout << u_raw_h[i] << " ";
 }
 std::cout << std::endl;

 std::cout << "Thrust: " << thrust_time << " s" << std::endl;
 std::cout << "Raw: " << raw_time << " s" << std::endl;

 free(u_raw_h);

 cudaFree(u_raw_d);
 cudaFree(uNew_raw_d);

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my testing, these lines:

```
uNew[0] = u[0];
uNew[N+1] = u[N+1];
```

are killing your thrust performance relative to the kernel method.  When I eliminate them, the results don't seem to be any different.  Compared to how your kernel is handling the boundary cases, the thrust code is using a very expensive method (`cudaMemcpy` operations, under the hood) to perform the boundary handling.

Since your thrust functor never actually writes to the boundary positions, it should be sufficient to write these values only once, rather than in a loop.

You can speed up your thrust performance significantly by doing a better job of handling the boundary cases.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. Suppose I did need to do something less trivial at the boundary (i.e. something different at each sweep). Is there a way to get Thrust to handle boundary cases as effectively as my kernel can?

Comment: You could make your functor handle it, by passing a `counting_iterator` index zipped up with the other quantities you have zipped together.  Then your functor code could look a lot like your kernel code, with a special case handling for specific indices.  There are other possibilities as well, such as running a fixup kernel, which may not be as expensive as what you are asking thrust to do currently.