# Calculating recursive array with CUDA

Tags: cuda

I have a recursive array definition.
Let it be

```
A(x, y + 1) = f(A(x - 1, y), A(x, y), A(x + 1, y))
```

First layer is initialized

```
A(x, 0) = g(x)
```

I want to calculate such an array layer by layer using CUDA. The question is what is preferred way to do such things. Should single kernel calculate an array `A(tid, y)` for `y` in `[1, height)` synchronizing on each step? Or should it just calculate single point, but be called multiple times? Or probably it is better to break a problem into bigger independent parts? E.g. this array can be split by rhombs in such a way that every whole rhomb can be calculated independently (without synchronization inside of rhomb) if previous layer of rhombs is done.

Will things become different if layers would be 2D rather than 1D?

I'm planning to calculate such an array with width ~ 10000 (probably less will be enough) and height 44100 every second. The problem is actually 3D (200x50x44100) if it matters. I just formulated it 2D for simplicity.

Comment: this looks like some kind of recurrence equation solver. Did you have a look at these papers: http://www.ijmo.org/papers/288-CS0005.pdf and http://www.thinkmind.org/download.php?articleid=future_computing_2012_2_20_30046 ?

Comment: Thank you, @m.s. These papers are on 1D problems. They are focused on optimizations. I'm just looking for simple straightforward solution that I can start with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A straightforward approach is probably just to start with what you outlined here:

> "Should single kernel calculate an array A(tid, y) for y in [1, height) synchronizing on each step?"

That should be pretty easy to implement.

An x "width" of 10,000 is in the ballpark to keep a GPU reasonably busy with that many threads.

For a complicated `f()` function, it may be challenging to be able to do 44100 iterations of these per second (an average iteration time of ~22 us). However, for a fairly simple `f()` function, it seems possible based on my quick test below.  We are benefitted by the fact that by launching kernels iteratively like this, much of the kernel launch overhead is hidden.

Here's a sample code written in thrust to demonstrate a proof of concept:

```
$ cat t708.cu
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/for_each.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

#define DSIZE 10000
#define YSIZE 2
#define NUM_ITER 44100
#define AVG_SIZE 3
#define DISP_WIDTH 5

struct f
{
  template <typename T>
  __host__ __device__
  void operator()(T t) {

    thrust::get<AVG_SIZE>(t)  = thrust::get<0>(t);
    thrust::get<AVG_SIZE>(t) += thrust::get<1>(t);
    thrust::get<AVG_SIZE>(t) += thrust::get<2>(t);

    thrust::get<AVG_SIZE>(t) /= AVG_SIZE;}
};

int main(){

  thrust::host_vector<float> h_A(DSIZE);
  for (int i =0; i < DSIZE; i++) h_A[i] = rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;  // A(x, 0) = g(x)
  thrust::device_vector<float> d_A[YSIZE];
  d_A[0].resize(h_A.size());
  d_A[1].resize(h_A.size());
  thrust::copy(h_A.begin(), h_A.end(), d_A[0].begin());
  thrust::copy(h_A.begin(), h_A.end(), d_A[1].begin());
  std::cout << "input left end: " << std::endl;
  thrust::copy(d_A[0].begin(), d_A[0].begin()+DISP_WIDTH, std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl << "input right end: " << std::endl;
  thrust::copy(d_A[0].end() - DISP_WIDTH, d_A[0].end(), std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;

  cudaEvent_t start, stop;
  cudaEventCreate(&start); cudaEventCreate(&stop);
  int cur = 0;
  int nxt = 1;
  cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ITER; i++){
    thrust::for_each(thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(d_A[cur].begin(), d_A[cur].begin()+1, d_A[cur].begin()+2, d_A[nxt].begin()+1)), thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(d_A[cur].end()-2, d_A[cur].end()-1, d_A[cur].end(), d_A[nxt].end()-1)), f());
    cur = (cur==0) ? 1:0;  // modify for a full storage in y
    nxt = (nxt==0) ? 1:0;}
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
  cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
  float et;
  cudaEventElapsedTime(&et, start, stop);
  std::cout << "elapsed time: " << et << "ms" << std::endl << "output left end: " << std::endl;
  thrust::copy(d_A[cur].begin(), d_A[cur].begin()+DISP_WIDTH, std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl << "output right end: " << std::endl;
  thrust::copy(d_A[cur].end() - DISP_WIDTH, d_A[cur].end(), std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}

$ nvcc -O3 -o t708 t708.cu
$ ./t708
input left end:
0.840188,0.394383,0.783099,0.79844,0.911647,
input right end:
0.865333,0.828169,0.311025,0.373209,0.888766,
elapsed time: 368.337ms
output left end:
0.840188,0.838681,0.837174,0.835667,0.83416,
output right end:
0.881355,0.883207,0.88506,0.886913,0.888766,
$
```

Notes:

1. The overall execution time for 44100 iterations of ~370ms suggests an average loop time of around 8us.
2. This was run on a Fedora20 system, with CUDA 7 and a Quadro5000 GPU.
3. I included display of the left and right hand side of the input and output data set to verify the "averaging" `f()` function (functor, in this case).  This is effectively a form of "relaxation" so we would expect the left end of the data set to converge to the left end value (which does not change) and the right end of the data set to converge to the right end value, with an approximately straight line between.
4. I only kept y(n) and y(n-1) data sets, for calculation and timing purposes.  If you need all y(0..44100) it's a fairly easy modification of the code.
5. If you're not familiar with thrust, the [quick start guide](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide) may get you up to speed, and you'll find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29421482/simple-thrust-code-performs-about-half-as-fast-as-my-naive-cuda-kernel-am-i-usi) covering a somewhat similar algorithm, and it should give you an idea of how this thrust method could be converted into an equivalent cuda kernel method.
6. In case it's not obvious, "synchronizing on each step" is accomplished by the cuda kernel call, which is a device-wide sync, implicit in the call to `thrust::for_each`.